# does anyone know a JS library that would work as epub

Tags: responsive-design, epub, html-rendering, ebook-reader

basically I am trying to render html pages as an ebook. I know how epub works. Its responsive and text highlight and making a note all those features there. But I am looking for similar solution using html pages. I have converted pdf to html ( each pdf page is a html page ) and want to render those html pages like epub3.

Features I need

- responsive
- text selection and highlight colors
- making notes
  and other epub3 features if there are any.

Anyone knows how to do this or any good libraries I can use.
glad for any help.

Answer (score 0):

epubjs is a good library to try out. It has the features which you mentioned. They also provide epubjs viewer which internally uses epubjs library to handle epub.

**epubjs github page:-**
https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js

**epubjs reader github page:-**
https://github.com/futurepress/epubjs-reader

**epubjs documentation:-**
http://epubjs.org/documentation/0.3/